# AWS S3 File Manipulation :: Find and replace a list of string patterns stored in a file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, replace

I have a large file in S3. And a list of strings which can be made available in a file or DB.
I want to search the S3 file for each and every occurance of every string listed in the file and replace with the string 'Unknown'.

**Is there any solution to search for all the strings in a single scan?** And replace with that pre-configured string rather than looping through the string list and scanning the file that many number of times?
I prefer using Python.

Comment: S3 doesn't have any way of doing this in-place. You have to download the file, make the replacements, then re-upload.

Comment: Even if i am downloading, can i search for all the string patterns in a single file scan?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if doing it in a single scan is a good goal. It may be faster to do one scan per word. Do any of the strings contain newlines, or one of the other strings?

Comment: No newlines. Unless we create the file as different rows in a csv file.

Comment: Then read one line at a time in the file, replace each string in that line, and write the new line to a new file. Now your problem is broken into subproblems which all have standard, easily searchable solutions.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use `sed` instead of Python? You could download, replace and upload in 3 lines.

Comment: Is there any way to stream each line to a new file in S3?